# Can't upgrade gcc on Mac

Tags: macos, gcc, qt-creator

So this is after having dropped $30 for Mac OS 10.7 and having downloaded XCode 4.3.2.  After installing the command line tools, the installed version of gcc is *still* 4.2.4.  I need 4.7.  I've installed it and set the `g++` link in `/usr/bin` to it.  But when I try to compile any program via QtCreator, I get

> unrecognized command line option `-Xarch_x86_64`

I found this discussed in a 3-year-old bug report [here](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/22924), but I really couldn't follow all the different shell commands etc. and my attempt to install liblastfm failed with the same error.  The comment [here](http://groups.google.com/group/capybara-webkit/browse_thread/thread/356ab5ac895346c7),

> The problem is that the GCC/G++ that is normally used to compile stuff
>   on Macs is actually just a wrapper.
>
> And this wrapper has Mac-Only arguments like -Xarch_x86_64, which then
>   get converted into the correct args.

Seems like it might be hitting the nail on the head.  Aaargh!  Surely there has to be some way to get around this?

Comment: You can use macports to install a newer version of gcc, if that's what you're asking. Apple switched over to using Clang as their C and C++ compiler, since GCC's licensing changed after 4.2.4 and they did not want to use a differently licensed GCC.

Comment: @birryree Aha.  I could not grasp how their supplied gcc version would stagnate at 4.2.4, now it is clear.  I'm unfamiliar with MacPorts (I'm generally a Linux user) but I will be looking into it, thanks.

Comment: @birryree I managed to install g++ using MacPorts (`g++-mp-4.7` now in `/opt/local/bin`), but when I try to run `gcc select` I get `The specified group g++ does not exist`.  This only occurs when I try to select g++, for gcc the command works fine.  Any tips here would be appreciated, and feel free to put it in an answer.

Comment: I think you have to do `gcc_select gcc47`, you can list versions with `gcc_select -l`.

Comment: @birryree Actually I think the command is now `port select --set g++ mp-g++47`.  This works for gcc (superficially--I get a 'success' message but `$ gcc` still fails trying to find llvm-gcc-4.2) but the g++ version fails with the error message I gave, which seems more fundamental.  Similarly `port select --list g++` works for gcc but fails on g++ with the same 'does not exist' error.

Answer (score 2):

I created a custom makespec - in QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/mkspecs, I copied the macx-g++ folder to macx-g++47. I then removed the "include(../common/g++macx.conf)" from that and included it's contents, except for the part that generates the error (i.e. the -X... thing).

I also finished with

```
QMAKE_CC         = gcc-mp-4.7
QMAKE_CXX        = g++-mp-4.7

QMAKE_LINK       = $$QMAKE_CXX
QMAKE_LINK_SHLIB = $$QMAKE_CXX
QMAKE_LINK_C       = $$QMAKE_CC
QMAKE_LINK_C_SHLIB = $$QMAKE_CC
```

...which is similar to the spec for macx-g++42.

Now, if I add '-spec macx-g++47' to the qmake args, it works.

A lot of effort for something simple...would love to know a better way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will look into this.  "A lot of effort for something simple"--Amen!!  Can *not* understand why Apple makes this so hard esp. since Mac OSX is UNIX-based.

Answer (score 1):

There are several sources for newer gcc versions for OSX. Here is a small selection:

http://hpc.sourceforge.net/ (currently gcc 4.8, previous versions might also be available)

http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries (has gcc 4.7.0 binary installer)

I assume that you did install the command line tools from within Xcode. Apple/Xcode is not always up to date with gcc, stability is more important here than bleeding edge.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into these.  I note though that my problem is not getting a new version of gcc (really, g++) on the computer, but rather getting QtCreator to send it the right arguments.  (I think the issue is broader than Qt but I'm not sure.)  It isn't immediately clear that these will help with that but I'm away from the Mac right now but I will try these out.